# CodeIgniter - Blank page at default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CI 3 in my last project on my localhost, then I uploaded it into a server. When I tried to load the web it's always show the blank page.
I have tried configure .htaccess, config.php, database.php, route.php it seems there shouldn't have any error, then I check index.php and tried to show some text.
I tried to insert :

```
echo "test"; die();
```

for every statement in index.php, at the first it show the "test" but it disappear after switch function for environment :

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;
case 'testing':
case 'production':
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    }
    else
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
break;

default:
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
    exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
```

}

in `case 'development'` it's still show the 'test' string but when after break in this case, the 'test' string disappear. 
 
Can anybody fix this?

Comment: Almost most cases, `Blank page = fatal error` It's just you can't see it because display errors is off. Turn it on or check your apache logs to see what is causing the error. Don't troubleshoot in the dark.

Comment: @PanamaJack well I'm not the one who managed the server, so I guess, I should find the solution without it

Comment: Good luck with that. I can be like a needle in a haystack. fatal errors can be anything from a library not loaded to invalid syntax etc. That's what logs are there for. You can also turn on display_errors in your php file. Just search how.

Comment: Have you followed the correct class and file naming way for Codeigniter as said here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @PanamaJack I have turn on display_errors but still show a blank page

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I'm sure I have name it correctly, but still you know...

Answer (score 0):

**Update!!**
I have finally get the answer. 
Actually when it routed into my default controller (maybe it's my fault or what I didn't remember it) there's `exit;` in construct function so it's never load any view.
Sorry for my less awareness